# HTML & CSS Tags within Tags Formatting

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #999;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>   
        <title>CSS Layouts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <header>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>Blog</li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>Links</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">col1</div>
            <div class="col">col2</div>
            <div class="col">col3</div>
        </div>
        <footer>2016 My Site</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

My challenge is to make the "My Page" h1 in line, as stated in the CSS

```css
header h1 {
    margin:0;
    display: inline;
}
```

In order to get the h1 header "My Page" to go inline with the unordered list, I need to move the h1 in the HTML to underneath of the `<nav>` opening tag (as opposed to where it is now underneath of the header opening tag), but I can't figure out why it will go inline when I do that but it won't when I leave it like it currently is.
It is my understanding that in CSS if you have the following:

```css
header h1{
    some styling here;
}
```

...that any h1's underneath of header will be affected, however, that is not happening in my code currently.

Comment: Your `nav` is `block`. That's the browser default. You should make that `inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `h1` *does* have the display inline, but the problem is that it is next to `nav` which is a block level element. Block elements take up as much width as they can, while inline elements only take up as much width as necessary (see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)). You'll need to change the display on the `nav` to `inline` or `inline-block` to stop it from taking up so much width.

Answer (score 0):

As you make your `ul` and `h1` `inline`, you don't do it with your `nav`, it still has `display: block` css property and takes full width.

Answer (score 0):

As other told you, the  element is style displayed as a block.

By the way, if you don't want "any h1's underneath of header to be affected" by that :

```
    header h1{
    some styling here;
}
```

You can write it this way :

```
header + h1 {
some styling here;
```

}

> Selects all "h1" elements that are placed immediately after "header" elements

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp